# How to read byte order endian BIG with Python?

Tags: python, pymodbus

Hello I try to read data from power meter using pymodbus. After I register the address, I get list of bytes like this
`result_ups.registers = [3468, 204, 0, 2080]`
I try to convert it to same value as show on power meter like this
`20434682080`
This is my project for monitoring system.

This is my code

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
import time


client_tcp = ModbusTcpClient('10.123.133.100',port=502)

while True:
    try:
        client_tcp.connect()
        while True:
            result_ups = client_tcp.read_holding_registers(1716,4,units=1,slave=1)
            decoder_ups = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result_ups.registers,byteorder=Endian.BIG,wordorder=Endian.LITTLE)
            kwh_ups = decoder_ups.decode_32bit_int()
            print(kwh_ups)
            time.sleep(1)
         
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to unpack binary data.

Comment: I already use struct but the result still not same like on power meter

Comment: Are those numbers supposed to be decimal or hex?

Comment: I suppose my naive approach if just doing `int(str(registers[1]) + str(registers[0]) + str(registers[3]))` don't cut it?

Comment: @Barmar it supposed to be decimal because i need to save the data into database.

Comment: @JonSG Oke, thank you for your answer. Maybe for now i use it for alternative of my case.

Comment: Numbers `3468, 204, 0, 2080` are not bytes! The maximal value for a byte would be 255. I would suggest reading the documentation for the library you are using to understand what you have to do, because your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the numbers by the appropriate powers of 10 to combine them as you show.

```
registers = [3468, 204, 0, 2080]
result = registers[3] + registers[0] * 10**4 + registers[1] * 10**8 + registers[2] * 10**12
print(result)
```

I'm not really sure why the results are in this order, it's not little-endian or big-endian.

Comment: But those cannot be bytes at all (that was a wrong assumption on the question)! Number 3468 alone would require two bytes.

Comment: You're right. Something is already decoding the bytes to numbers, I've updated my answer to use a more appropriate term.